# Delphi : load xml file within a thread

Tags: xml, multithreading, delphi

I'm trying to load an XML file within a thread in Delphi, but I'm getting this error message:

> Microsoft MSXML is not installed

However, my code works fine outside of the thread!

Here's my code :

```
procedure NewThread.Execute;
begin
  XMLDocument1 := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
  XMLDocument1.Active := True;
  XMLDocument1.LoadFromXML('document.xml');
end;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try calling CoInitialize and CoUninitialize within context of the thread

Comment: I just tried   CoInitialize(nil);
 XMLDocument1 := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
XMLDocument1.Active := True;
XMLDocument1.LoadFromXML('document.xml');
  CoUninitialize; but I'm getting the same error

Comment: it's ok thanks for your help

Comment: MSXML is based on ActiveX/COM technology. The error means the MSXML COM object could not be instantiated.  Calling `Co(Un)Initialize` inside the thread context is absolutely essential. If you are doing that now (and make sure you `Free` the `XMLDocument` before calling `CoUninitialize`), and are still getting the error, then either MSXML is really not installed, or something else is blocking the COM object from being instantiated. And BTW, `LoadFromXML()` expects an actual XML string, not a filename. Use `LoadFromFile()` for that instead.

Comment: You should not be using `TXMLDocument.Create(Application)` in a thread anyway (specifying an `Owner` is not thread-safe). Pass `nil` for the `Owner` instead (`TXMLDocument.Create(nil)`), but make sure your `XMLDocument1` variable is typed as `IXMLDocument` instead of `TXMLDocument` (read the documentation for why). In which case, you should just use the standalone `LoadXMLDocument()` or `LoadXMLData()` function instead of instantiating `TXMLDocument` directly.

Comment: BTW, which version of Delphi are you actually using?  It makes a difference in how `TXMLDocument` instantiates MSXML at runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487282/com-object-methods-are-not-executed-on-the-thread-that-coinitialize-d-and-create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSXML uses COM objects, the error message means the MSXML COM objects failed to instantiate.

First Step is to always check if MSXML is indeed installed on your machine, and then you MUST call `CoInitialize/CoUninitialize` in every thread context that accesses COM objects, and maybe try wrapping it with a try/finally statement

Comment: how to check if MSXML is installed ?

Comment: You can just check if the MSXML.dll file exist in your Windows directory

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot

Comment: @Fero68 it is not enough to have the DLL present, its COM objects have to be registered in the Registry as well.

Comment: @Remy Thats very true